# PHP Sql Save Calender Week in Db

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin, int

How do I save the current Calender week into my database(phpmyadmin).
I did so far:

```
    /**
     * current calenderweek
     */
    $date = new DateTime();
    echo $date->format('W');

    /*
     * Is button pushed?
     */
     if(isset($_POST['saveButton'])) {

        . . .      

        $data = array(
            'id'        => $result['id'],
            'firstname' => $result['firstname'],
            'lastname'  => $result['lastname'],
            'calender_week' => $date->format('W') 
            );
      }
```

I tried here to save the current calender week ( with PDO ) into my databse,
but it did not work. (id, firstname, lastname works by the way)
The databasefield is an integer and give me this:

> 2147483647

But if I echo this:

```
/**
 * current calenderweek
 */
$date = new DateTime();
echo $date->format('W');
```

it shows me the correct calender week of 39.

How do I solve this issue, I just want to display the current calenderweek.

Comment: What do you use data type of field in DB? If you want to save data in timestamp format use `int` date type field. Any use `varchar`

Comment: I use an integer /INT as an datatype in my DB for this field

Comment: You'll need to provide more code, around inserting into your DB. Database schema ...etc. The value you have provided is more of a timestamp than week of year. Also date('W') will suffice for what you're after.

Comment: It worked now I forgot to change it in my other class my bad.
If anybody needs a calender week in a databse as an int above code works ty for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the MySQL function `WEEK()`